# How to edit the "New" submenu of the right-click menu in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to edit the "New" submenu when I use the right-clik on a project in the Project Explorer ? "Customize perspective" settings don't seem to have any effect on it. In my Eclipse on Ubuntu I have directly the wizards that I want in this submenu, but in my Eclipse on Windows I have to click on "Other..." to find the right wizard. Thanks.

Comment: That should be in Customize Perspective - on the "Shortcuts" tab, "New" submenu.

Comment: No, this has no effect on the "New" submenu of the right-clik menu.

Comment: As far as I can see that menu is not configurable, only plug-ins can add to it.

Answer (score 0):

open eclipse, then go to Window menu, select Customize perspective...

a windows appears. it has for tabs.

Tool bar visiblity
Menu visiblity
Command Groups Availablity
Shortcuts
select Menu visiblity tab, it will shows all menus with tree view.

[image]

then expand tree view of File then do same for the New which is sub tree of File.

[image]

now select All of those project types that you want, then click Ok.